# ActiveRecord and illegal column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, limesurvey

I want to access the Limesurvey database via ActiveRecord. Some tables have column names like '79924X192X1240'. When I want to access the model, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
                def 79924X192X1240=(original_time)
                         ^):
```

I guess, the error appears, because it's not allowed, that a method starts with a digit. But I can't alter the column name, because Limesurvey generates these columns.

This error appears only if the data type of a column (like 79924X192X1240) is datetime. Other data types like varchar don't make any problems.

How can I access these datetime columns, too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do raw sql queries for that.  ActiveRecord is written for ruby which does not allow method names to start with numbers.  Since each column on the table is equivalent to a method, then trying to access that information will throw a syntax error every time.

You need to use: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

Comment: Right, but I want to access them with ActiveRecord. Furthermore, the other data types work with these names (79924X192X1240).. So either these column names work for no data types or it's a bug and it should work with the datetime data type, too.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the columns by using the hash: `.attributes`?